# Animating element dimensions using CSS transform transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to achieve a smooth animation (60 fps) of header's height, which is initially 100% height of window, while the target (after clicking nav link) is fixed (80px). Simply using css transition on height is just not smooth enough, as well as using jQuery animate function. I'm using transform transitions for other elements, but I just have no idea, how could I make this one work properly. I prefer using css on this, but jq solution would also be fine.

This is the page: http://mariuszbrozek.com/test

HTML looks like this:

```
<header>
    <nav>...</nav>
</header>
<section class="content">
    ...
</section>
<footer>
    ...
</footer>
```

At the beginning, content section is not displayed, it appears after clicking nav link.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, make a fiddle if you can (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: In fact, I find it so confusing, that I haven't come up with any idea that wouldn't be a total overkill. But I can show you my page to clarify what I'm trying to do. [mariuszbrozek.com](http://mariuszbrozek.com/test/)
For now animations isn't very good, I want to fix them using cubic-bezier, and that's why I want to start with making them absolutely smooth.

Comment: They play very smooth in my browser, but thats cause I have a high end pc. I suggest you try using filters where you can for the blurring and such http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html as for the animations going choppy, it all depends on the cpu power the end user has. The only way to get really consistent hardware accellerated experience is by using a canvas, but that gives its own problems. By using hardware accelerated blurring for the edges and elements you save a lot of cpu time having to calculate that. And maybe make the translition take more time for more smooth

Comment: All animations are using css transform, except problematic one - header's height using jQuery animate function. And I really don't think it's a matter of pc's performance, because it's just not possible to animate css height property with 60fps. 
[Check out this source](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

Comment: Well, lets forget for a moment about overhead. You want to do an animation. An animation consists of frames. Lets say you want to do this in 60 frames for smooth experience. hardcode 60 stages in you page with different percentual elevations. make the smallest z-index 1 and the highest z-index 60. Then hide them all on page load. Then to animate them in just show() them one by one, each function starting when the other one is finished $('first').show({duration:50}).done($('second').show({duratio:50}).done(etc...). I would suggest caching the jquery objects beforehand to stop lookup times.